# Local Effective actions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, effective-field-theory, locality

While studying partition functions in general, i came across a statement which says that "the partition function of a theory without gapless
excitations must be a local functional of the background fields; therefore, the effective action
is local" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02607v2, Section 2) . My question is,

1) By effective action, i am supposed to understand the effective action for the low lying energy states below the energy gap?

2) This is a local functional assuming there are no perturbations comparable to the energy gap? or am i getting something wrong conceptually?

3) For theories with gapless excitations, is it always local?